# jQuery cannot be accessed properly after being loaded dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write a small check that will test for jQuery, and if not present, dynamically load a copy so that a script can be run by it. It sets to no conflict in case anything else is present that also uses $, and then runs the script - a small menu.

However, upon actually testing this jQuery is loaded from the script, but fails to execute: "jQuery is not defined."

I know that jQuery has to come first before any functions that use it, but is there any way to fix this when it is dynamically installed?

```
(function() {
    console.log("Loaded");
   if(!window.jQuery) {
       var script = document.createElement('script');
       script.type = "text/javascript";
       script.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js";
       document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
       jQuery.noConflict(); 
   }
})();
```

Comment: If your menu uses jQuery, why not add the menu code in the IF from above? Is it too much code? The issue here is that you run a code that requires jQuery BEFORE even jQuery gets to be loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not waiting until the script has loaded.

```
 script.onload = function(){
     // do whatever
 };
```

Comment: That was it. I recognized it was an onLoad issue, but was trying to put it into document. Thank you!